# Why does java.lang.Iterable.forEach() invoke requireNonNull()?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, java-8

This is in `java.lang.Iterable`:

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

and this is `java.util.Objects.requireNonNull()`:

```
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    return obj;
}
```

The way I understand it, if the iterable is non-empty, and I pass a null action, it will throw a null pointer exception **anyway**, so what is the point of checking the action, and throwing the exact same exception if found to be null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done to achieve consistent behavior between situations when your iterable is empty and when it is non-empty. Without this check done upfront, the method would complete successfully when you pass `null` action, but the iterable is empty.

However, this would contradict the documentation, which says that `NullPointerException` is always thrown if the specified action is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You answered it yourself: if the iterable is empty, the method must still throw a `NullPointerException`. [Quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> **Throws:**
>   `NullPointerException` - if the specified action is null